# Google analytics 4 with Next js

Tags: events, next.js, google-analytics, real-time, gtag.js

The problem that I have is that I'm trying to add Google Analytics to My Next.js app and there are two problems. The first problem is that I can't see collect message in network tab in Chrome but in Microsoft Edge is visible. Also dataLayer in Chrome when logged to the console doesn't show any events while Edge shows events.
The second problem is that I still have "No data received" in my Google Analytics dashboard and Realtime doesn't show anything. This is my code
_app.js

```
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import { appWithTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import { Raleway } from "next/font/google";
import Head from "next/head";
import Script from "next/script";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

import GoogleAnalytics from "@/components/GoogleAnalyitics";
const CookieBanner = dynamic(() => import("../components/CookieBanner"), {
  ssr: false,
});
const raleway = Raleway({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-ral",
});
const ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS;
function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
      </Head>

      <main className={`${raleway.variable} font-ral min-h-screen w-full`}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <CookieBanner></CookieBanner>
        <Script id="tawk" strategy="lazyOnload">
          {`var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
         (function(){
           var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
           s1.async=true;
           s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/64367ade4247f20fefeb2cc2/1gtqcvtgf';
           s1.charset='UTF-8';
           s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
           s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
           })()`}
        </Script>
        <GoogleAnalytics GA_MEASUREMENT_ID={ID}></GoogleAnalytics>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default appWithTranslation(App);
```

GoogleAnalytics.js

```
import Script from "next/script";
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { pageview } from "@/lib/gtagHelper";
export default function GoogleAnalytics({ GA_MEASUREMENT_ID }) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = pathname + searchParams.toString();

    pageview(GA_MEASUREMENT_ID, url);
  }, [pathname, searchParams, GA_MEASUREMENT_ID]);
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}`}
      />
      <Script
        id="google-analytics"
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                gtag('js', new Date());

                gtag('consent', 'default', {
                    'analytics_storage': 'denied'
                });
                
                gtag('config', '${GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}', {
                    page_path: window.location.pathname,
                });
                `,
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

gtagHelper.js

```
export const GA_TRACKING_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS;

// https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages
export const pageview = (url) => {
  window.gtag("config", GA_TRACKING_ID, {
    page_path: url,
  });
};

// https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events
export const event = ({ action, category, label, value }) => {
  window.gtag("event", action, {
    event_category: category,
    event_label: label,
    value: value,
  });
};
```

CookieBanner.js

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { getLocalStorage, setLocalStorage } from "@/lib/storageHelper";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function CookieBanner() {
  const [cookieConsent, setCookieConsent] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedCookieConsent = getLocalStorage("cookie_consent", null);

    setCookieConsent(storedCookieConsent);
  }, [setCookieConsent]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newValue = cookieConsent ? "granted" : "denied";

    window.gtag("consent", "update", {
      analytics_storage: newValue,
    });

    setLocalStorage("cookie_consent", cookieConsent);
  }, [cookieConsent]);
  return (
    <div
      className={`${
        cookieConsent !== null ? "hidden" : "flex"
      } my-10 mx-auto w-max fixed bottom-0 left-0 right-0  px-3 md:px-4 py-3 justify-between items-center flex-col sm:flex-row gap-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow`}
    >
      <div className="text-center">
        <Link href="/info/cookies">
          <p className="whitespace-nowrap">
            We use{" "}
            <span className="font-bold text-sky-400 mx-1"> cookies </span> on
            our site.
          </p>
        </Link>
      </div>

      <div className="flex gap-2">
        <button
          onClick={() => setCookieConsent(false)}
          className="px-5 py-2 text-gray-700 rounded-md border-gray-900"
        >
          Decline
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => setCookieConsent(true)}
          className="bg-primary px-5 py-2 text-white rounded-lg whitespace-nowrap"
        >
          Allow Cookies
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to add Google Analyitics to my page and I was expecting to see changes in realtime on Google Analytics dashboard

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is going to help, but in your _app.js code, there's a typo in the import:

```
import GoogleAnalytics from "@/components/GoogleAnalyitics";
```

Spelt "Analytics" wrong at the end.

Comment: It was an ad blocker.